# Python Azure-Storage 0.33.0 broken with Azure WebApp

Tags: python, azure, flask

I have this really weird issue with Flask app crashing when importing azure.storage. So I have this code:

```
from azure.storage.queue import QueueService
```

As soon as I deploy it to Azure, it fails. Any ideas ? I have put both Azure and Azure-Storage in requirements.txt.

What could possibly be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
Debugging is turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure-storage 0.33.0 (latest as of now) has a dependency of cryptography package, which fails to install, take a look here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/issues/219

workaround: use earlier version, 0.32.0, for example